# Conformal symmetry of Navier-Stokes?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

This question is in reference to the paper [arXiv:0810.1545](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1545)

- Can someone help understand this scaling argument and the proof(?) that there is a conformal symmetry in Navier-Stoke's equation? (..am I even reading the result right?..)
- Is one saying that the equations 3.4 encode the full symmetry of equation 1.1? 
  If yes, how? What calculation do I need to do to check that?

  I am unable to understand how to read 3.4
- Also what role does equation 2.9 play?
  Are the new symmetries specific to the form 2.9 or they apply to the general 1.1?
- Also 2.9 and 1.1 don't seem to be the "same" as apparently claimed- 2.9 has the time derivative of a0 and also a viscosity-Ricci term. What's going on?

Comment: Would you please consider making this question self-contained?

Comment: I've only read the paper very briefly, but note that NS itself is clearly not conformally invariant ($\nu$ is dimensionful). Minwalla + friends discuss a particular scaling limit, which should enjoy more symmetries.
(3.4) defines how the vector $v^i = v^i(x,t)$ transforms (under infinitesimal transformations). They decompose the conformal group in some special non-relativistic way, but qualitatively there's nothing new (compared to the ordinary conformal group).

Comment: Which rascal has downvoted this question ...?! Even though I agree that it would be much better to type the equations into the question, this is no reason to downvote, leaving a comment as user1504 did is enough!

Comment: @Vibert So how does one check that the 3.4 are the symmetries of the equation 1.1 in some scaling limit? May be you can heuristically sketch the checking calculation - like the steps by which one one proves that in some scaling limit (which one?) is 3.4 a symmetry of (1.1? 2.9?).

Comment: @Vibert To pick an example - if $M_{ik}$ acts on $v^j$ as stated at the end of $3.4$ then that implies which transformation on $v_i$ that will keep (1.1? 2.9?) invariant and in which limit?

Comment: @Anirbit: I'd love to help you out, but I have a finite amount of time to do so ;) and close-reading a paper I've never seen before would take hours...

Comment: @Vibert I can understand. Is this fact about NS well-known in literature elsewhere also? Like any other place which has a more pedagogic explanation of this? The first line of the paragraph above 3.4 says _"Navier-Stokes equations en
joy invariance under a conformal sym-
metry group"_  - which is a very powerful claim!